# Parse android strings.xml from java server application

Tags: android, servlets, localization

I have a simple Android app that uses Strings.xml for localization.

I would like to make a web app that does the same thing and uses
the same String resources.

Is it possible to use the Android library for string parsing from a
non Android java application ?

Comment: string.xml is an xml file you can parse it using any parser

Comment: The Android parser does some extra stuff like handling multipart strings  `    <string name="level_up">Congratulations !!! you passed %1$s \n and earned %2$d points. You now have %3$d total points.\n Now it\'s time to practice %4$s </string>
`   Parsing the XML and then handling the multi-part strings starts feeling non-trivial to me.